# stopping Or interrupting browser from making further AJAX calls

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I have  a question with respect to stopping/interrupting browser from making further calls .

In our Application We have a series of (10) **AJAX calls** that will made to middleware during **login process** .

All these (10) asynchronous calls and hit the middleware during the logon process .

My question is , I need to stop the browser once it makes 3 calls ??

Just for information ,( I use google chrome/firefox /safari)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered simply having a boolean variable that tells it whether or not to continue with the ajax calls? For example a variable called allowAjax set to true, initially. Whenever the condition occurs that you want to stop making the ajax calls, set it to false. Before each ajax call, check the allowAjax variable...

Comment: Front End part is managed by different person /people . I am into java part so asking if this can be possible with developer tools or any such tool ??

Comment: You need to go modify your question and provide specifics. Your question mentions nothing about language. It mentions browser and google-chrome which, to me, means javascript, not java. You need to provide details about the setup. What's the client, what's the server, what exactly are you trying to accomplish. Please be detailed because people aren't going to want to spend days going back and forth with you dragging out details.